# Trying to write a function that says if they are relatively prime numbers. Where is my error?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns true or false after taking two separate integers as an argument and determines whether or not they are relatively prime numbers.
I'm getting the correct output sometimes, but not all the time. Does anyone know what the issue here could be?
Here's my code.

```
def is_relatively_prime(n, m):
while m != 0:
    n % m
    return(n, m) == 1
```

Comment: Please give an example of when you're not getting the correct output

Comment: is_relatively_prime(12, 13). I should be getting True, but I'm getting False.

Comment: How so?? @superb rain

Comment: First line would better say "are" instead of "is". Second line's `while` makes no sense if you're going to `return` in the first iteration anyway. Third line does a calculation and ignores the result. Fourth line is a complicated nonsensical way to write `return False`, as a tuple will never equal 1. Plus indentation errors.

Comment: @superbrain I'm sorry, I'm new to programming and I'm having a difficult time with these challenges.

Comment: @heth1234 dont forget to accept an answer !

Answer (score 3):

Remove the fake-loop and throw-away modulo calculation. And *(a, b)* is a [notation for gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Notation) in math, but not in Python. Fixed:

```
from math import gcd

def are_relatively_prime(n, m):
    return gcd(n, m) == 1
```

Or write the typical gcd algorithm yourself:

```
def are_relatively_prime(n, m):
    while m:
        n, m = m, n % m
    return abs(n) == 1
```

Comment: this is best answer @heth1234

Comment: I'm not able to use imports on this challenge. @frederic

Comment: @heth1234 See the added solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your snippet doing anything close to what you wanted to do. why not try the below snippet it might just save you some precious time.

```
def is_relatively_prime(n, m):
    divisible = 1
    n = abs(n)
    m = abs(m)
    while not(divisible > n) and not(divisible > m):
        divisible += 1
        if n % divisible == 0 and m % divisible == 0:
            return False
    return True


is_relatively_prime(12,13) # this should return true
```

Comment: is 3 and 3 not coprime? my understanding is two integer are relatively prime if there is no integer greater than one that divides them both. I stand to be corrected.

Comment: Well, there *is* an integer greater than one that divides them both.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, 3 can divide both integer, updating the snippet now

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @superbrain and Pumpkin

Comment: Still not quite right, claims that -2 and -4 are relatively prime.

Comment: it has been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Why the while loop ? It ends in the first run. I think your code should be like this:

```py
def is_relatively_prime(n, m):
    return n % m == 1
```

In your original code:
`n % m` will calculate something and do nothing with the result, and `return (n, m) == 1` is not comparing n and m with 1, but a tuple.

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes in the code that appears that is working better now:

```
def is_relatively_prime(n, m):
while m != 0:
    if n % m != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```